# Performance Issue with Spark dataframe exist

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Which is recommended and why in respect of performance
spark.dataframe.count() or spark.dataframe.take(1).

Comment: In what context you asking this question, do you want to check whether the data frame has record  or not ?

Comment: @nilesh1212 we should consider both cases, depending on whether data frame has record or not, we need to throw execption.

Comment: In that case spark.dataframe.take(1) is efficient approach

Comment: @nilesh1212 Please also explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`take(1)` is more efficient than `count()`. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala) of RDD;

> Take the first num elements of the RDD. It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit.

For your use case `isEmpty()` should be the best option. It's source code is using take(1) yet again;

```scala
def isEmpty(): Boolean = withScope {
    partitions.length == 0 || take(1).length == 0
}
```